# MVC - RouteLink and Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I'd like this output:

```
<a href="\Catalog\Flooring">
    <img src="http://site.com/dot.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" alt="" />
    <span>Some text here</span>
</a>
```

using a RouteLink similar to:

```
<%= Html.RouteLink(myFPV.ProductTypeName, "CatalogType", new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Types", group = myFPV.ProductGroupName, type = myFPV.ProductTypeName })%>
```

I cannot figure out how to add an `<img>` and `<span>` (with text) tags inside my `<a>` tag.

Make sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first parameter of the RouteLink method is for the link text. But unfortunately, it gets encoded automatically, so you cannot send <, > characters to it. (Well, you can. But they'd get encoded.)

Take a look at [this page](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx).

> Route values are URL encoded automatically. For example, the string “Hello World!” is
>   encoded to “Hello%20World!”.
>
> #### Rendering Image Links
>
> Unfortunately, you can’t use the
>   Html.ActionLink() helper to render an
>   image link. Because the
>   Html.ActionLink() helper HTML encodes
>   its link text automatically, you
>   cannot pass an  tag to this
>   method and expect the tag to render as
>   an image.
>
> Instead, you need to use the
>   Url.Action() helper to generate the
>   proper link. Here’s how you can
>   generate a delete link with an image:
>
> ```
> <a href="<%= Url.Action("Delete") %>">
>   <img src="../../Content/Delete.png" alt="Delete" style="border:0px" />
> </a>
> ```

Answer (score 9):

I suggest use the Url.RouteUrl.

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Default", new { action = "Index", controller = "Department", id = 1 })">
 <img src="http://site.com/dot.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" alt="" />  </a>
```

Comment: That's what I ended up using, this answer deserves more than it got, I'm  going to make it happen.

Comment: Indeed the most appropriate answer to this question. Take my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

There is a better option to do that. you should try some thing like

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("index-lang")">
  <img src="~/images/logo.png" alt="">
 </a>
```

where the "index-lang" is the route name in route mapping table.

Comment: works perfect, thx added this to the RouteConfig: routes.MapRoute("Index", "Index", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }); and was able to use <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("Index")">
  <img src="~/images/logo.png" alt="">
 </a> on my website logo