# html helper html.RouteLink is it possible to place Image? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

>>", new { page = (Model.PageIndex + 1) },null)%>

Is it possible to set image instead ">>>" and how?

Take care,
Ragims

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC - RouteLink and Image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712593/mvc-routelink-and-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate.

[MVC - RouteLink and Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712593/mvc-routelink-and-image)

Please check out the Link in that question and view the provided examples for the custom ImageLink Helper.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<%= Url.RouteUrl(new { page = (Model.PageIndex + 1) })">
    <img src="next.jpg" />
</a>
```

I'm unsure of the exact syntax, don't have ASP.NET MVC on the current machine.

Comment: @Ragims what happens when you use the first way?

Comment: @Craig: Thank you, I've removed that option.

Comment: Doesn't `RouteLink()` return an anchor tag?

Comment: @Yuriy meant to write `Url.RouteUrl`. There is no `Url.RouteLink`